# Windows 11 connecting to public WiFi - too many captive portal tabs

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-11, captive-portal

After upgrading to Windows 11, when I am trying to connect some public WiFi with captive portals (as I am now on an airplane), the system keeps opening captive portal tabs even after logging in sucessfully, or in many cases, preventing me from completing the login process altogether at the first place.

This seems to be happening to other people as well with no clear solutions other than restarting/re-enabling WiFi：

1. https://www.reddit.com/r/PFSENSE/comments/11lii62/windows_11_captive_portal_opens_in_a_loop
2. https://www.reddit.com/r/fortinet/comments/11dg14r/fortigate_captive_portal_opening_automatically/

Default browser is Chrome. Setting it to Edge as suggested in the first link doesn't solve the issue.

Is there a fix for this issue? Alternatively, is it possible to simply disable automatic captive portal detection for one or all networks?

Comment: @Peregrino69 Chrome. Setting Edge as default did not solve the problem.

Comment: I added this to the question. Best to edit the question to add new info, as it's easier to get from there than from the comments.

Comment: Does it happen using Firefox and [this setting](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/enable-or-disable-firefox-network-captive-portal-service)?

Comment: @harrymc I'd have to try it next time I connect to a public wifi. But a priori I would say it is not related to Firefox settings, since the captive portal test domain is msftconnecttest.com so I assume it is Windows that is prompting the portal pages.

Answer (score 0):

Heres some forum posts relating to preventing windows from opening captive portals.

the posts suggest making a regedit to stop windows opening the captive portals, if thats an option for you:

> The solution is as simple as setting this registry key to 0:
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NlaSvc\Parameters\Internet\EnableActiveProbing

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/disable-browser-automatically-opening-while/2c1e598d-690c-4a08-98fe-84ce1e522958

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-do-i-stop-windows-10-from-automatically/d7a3c3f2-c0c1-4027-b10b-9b2c79c4d432

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43491862